# Binary words graph

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the graph whose vertices are formed by binary word of length $k$ and wherein two words form an edge iff they differ in two digits, or if they differ in all digits.
For example, vertex 1110 is adjacent to the 0111, 0100 or 0001, but not to 1100
Depending on $k$ decide whether the graph is Eulerian or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start with the following observation: the graph is connected iff $k$ is odd or $k=0$.

The case $k=0$ is trivially connected, consisting of only one vertex.  If $k$ is odd, then we may get from any vertex $v$ to any other vertex $w$ with one bit flipped, by first flipping all bits, and then flipping the other $k-1$ bits in pairs.  Thus we can reach any vertex from any other, so the graph is connected.  Finally, if $k>0$ is even, then the graph has at least (one could show precisely) two connected components: vertices with an even number of $1$ and vertices with an odd number.  It is easy to see that any edge starting from an even vertex must land on another even vertex.  When $k>0$ there are vertices of each type so the graph is disconnected.

So, let's ignore the small cases $k=0,1$ which have been covered above and in the comments.  If the graph is Eulerian then necessarily $k$ is odd.  Furthermore the graph is regular so for $k>1$ we cannot have any odd-degree vertices (else there are $>2$ of them), so an equivalent condition is that $k$ is odd and the degree is even.

Finally, the degree (for $k>2$) is given by $C(k,2)+1$: for any vertex, there are $C(k,2)$ choices of two bit positions to flip, or we could flip all bits (which is a distinct vertex when $k>2$).  This degree is even iff $C(k,2) = k(k-1)/2$ is odd, which is equivalent (for $k$ odd) to $(k-1)/2$ being odd, so $(k-1)/2 = 2m+1$ for some nonnegative integer $m$, i.e. $k=4m+3$.

I leave it to the OP to summarize this into one comprehensive statement of the precise values of $k$ for which the graph is Eulerian.

Comment: When $k$ is odd, not only is the graph connected, but its diameter can be computed explicitly: since it's transitive, we need only consider the maximum distance to $0\cdots0$.  It is not hard to see that bit strings of even Hamming weight are at distance $\le (k-1)/2$ and bit strings of odd weight are at distance $\le (k+1)/2$, the most distant being $0\cdots01$.